# Combining SQL Views loses efficency

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 views:

```
View1
ID, A1, A2, A3, A4, ..., Ax

View2
ID, B1, B2, B3, B4, ..., By

View3
ID, C1, C2, C3, C4, ..., Cz
```

I also have a temporary table that contains a list of ID values that I'm interested in.  If I do a query between any view and do an inner join with my table of ID values the results are returned almost immediately.

```
select ViewX.*
from #Ids 
inner join ViewX on ViewX.ID = #IDs.ID
```

However if I do a combination of any 2 views and an inner join with the temporary table then the results can take much longer (15-25 seconds).

```
select ViewX.*, ViewY.*
from #IDs 
inner join ViewX on ViewX.ID = #IDs.ID
inner join ViewY on ViewY.ID = #IDs.ID
```

So a two part question: why does combining more than one view take **SO** much longer, and what's the fix to make it more efficient?

Some additional background information; View2 and View3 columns are sub-queries, simply creating a new view with all of the columns from each of the views becomes even less efficient than it is now.

Thanks

---

[image]

I've been working on the problem and I've got it down to one part.  Here is the query.

```
    select
        VPayersOrderTracking.*,
        (
            select 
                count(todsdMRID.TOrderDetailsStatusDocumentsId) 
                from #orderDetailsReturn as odrMRID
                inner join TOrderDetailsStatus as todsMRID on todsMRID.TOrderDetailsId = odrMRID.TOrderDetailsId
                inner join TOrderDetailsStatusDocuments as todsdMRID on todsdMRID.TOrderDetailsStatusDocumentsId = todsMRID.TOrderDetailsStatusId 
                inner join LDocumentTypes as ldtMRID on ldtMRID.LDocumentTypesId = todsdMRID.LDocumentTypesId 
                where odrMRID.TOrderDetailsId = odr.TOrderDetailsId and ldtMRID.IsReportTypeDocument = 1
        ) as MedicalReportsIncludingDelectedCount,
        from #orderDetailsReturn as odr
        inner join VPayersOrderTracking on odr.TOrderDetailsId = VPayersOrderTracking.TOrderDetailsId
        inner join VProvidersTrackingDocuments on VProvidersTrackingDocuments.TOrderDetailsId = odr.TOrderDetailsId 
        order by
            VPayersOrderTracking.TOrderHeadersId desc, VPayersOrderTracking.SequenceNumber
```

If I run this query without the sub-query it returns all the records in less than 1 second.  If I include the query it takes about 10 seconds to return the same number of rows.  Normally there would be 4 such sub-queries which of course just increases the time proportionally.

Comment: The only way to answer your question is to view your execution plan. Its specific to *your* setup, not related to the combination of views temp tables you mention. The database engine build an execution plan taking into account the entire query, and views are inlined i.e. the view SQL is combined into the full query. So different combinations of views are going to cause totally different execution plans. Google paste the plan.

Answer (score 0):

It might be better if you rewrite this views as `Inline Table-Valued Function` - basically, it is a view that have parameters.

If such case, you will be able to filter data initially. For example, if you are extracting IDs for particular entity (country, language, brand, etc.) you will be able to pass this value as parameter to the view and return x % of rows instead 100% of the rows.

Another way of optimizing the view is to make it indexed view, but there are [some requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15#additional-requirements) as one is not to have sub-queries as you have.

If the views logic is complicated and cannot be rewritten, you may want to create this views as tables using a trigger or stored procedure to materializing the results.

And the starting point will be share the views definitions and ask for help in order to optimize them.

Comment: I'm not a DBA so I'm a bit out of my element.  However what you said got me thinking and and I was able to improve the performance.  It's still not where I'd like it to be.  I think you are right that the sub query's logic is where the most gain can be obtained.  I'll show some of the sub query code in the next comment.

Comment: select
 #temp.orderId,
 (
  select
   count(documents.documentsId)
  from
   #temp as T
  inner join status on T.orderId = status.orderId
  inner join documents on status.documentsId = documents.documentsId
  where
   T.orderId = #temp.orderId and documents.status = 1
 )
from #temp

Comment: @tdinpsp I see. This can be done without sub-query, but I am guessing you have other similar sub-queries - if you can post the whole statement I can try to simplify it.

Comment: I've added where I'm at today above.